# Unique Particle Attribution - XSD issue

Tags: xml, xsd

Dynamically i receive either of these XML from MQ. 
All elements should be in same sequence and all are mandatory fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ABC xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <IDEN>
   <A>A</A>
   <B>B</B>
   <C>C</C>
  </IDEN>
</ABC>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ABC xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <IDEN>
   <A>A</A>
   <BB>BB</BB>
   <C>C</C>
  </IDEN>
</ABC>
```

XSD :

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ABC">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="IDEN">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="A"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="B"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="C"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="A"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="BB"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="C"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Also tried

Error :

> Cos-nonambig: A And A (or Elements From Their Substitution Group)
>   Violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During Validation Against This
>   Schema, Ambiguity Would Be Created For Those Two Particles

I know many people had the same problem earlier, but none of their solutions has helped me. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to common elements between sequences. The second sequence differs only by its middle element, at which point only the parser can identify the schema definition. The common elements (`<A/>` and `<C/>`) cannot be distinguished before the sequence is fully parsed. Schema validation is done element by element. Instead here the parser would have to delay validation until the second element is encountered. I don't believe this is how parsers work. Instead what I suggest is this:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ABC">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="IDEN">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="A"/>
              <xs:choice>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="B"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="BB"/>
              </xs:choice>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="C"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

In short, the parser shall know, in a deterministic fashion, when on an element *and* from the element itself *only*, not from subsequent elements what schema component to use for validation.